# Erro de criação de form com entity framework

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net-mvc

Está acontecendo um erro que eu não consigo identificar

Eu sei que o BeginForm no Create.html do entity framework, tem algumas opções de envio de se fazer sobrecarga, uma delas é a que estou usando, cujo pede, ActionName, ControllerName, FormMethod e htmlAttributes, então estou fazendo da seguinte forma

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "AreaClientes", FormMethod.Post, new { id= "formCrud" }))
```

Acontece que o form criado me retorna com

`<form action="/AreaClientes/Create/Undefined">`

Esse undefined que não estou sabendo da onde está surgindo

Quando eu mudo para 
 `<form action="/AreaClientes/Create">`o insert funciona perfeitamente

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue também o c#, e os javascripts que fazem o controle do mesmo

```js
/* EnviarFormulario.js  **/

var btnAcao = $("input[type='button']");
var formulario = $("#formCrud");

btnAcao.on("click", submeter);

function submeter() {
    if (formulario.valid ())
    {

        var url = formulario.prop("action");
        
        var metodo = formulario.prop("method");

        var dadosFormulario = formulario.serialize();

        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: metodo,
            data: dadosFormulario,
            success: tratarRetorno
        });
    }
}

function tratarRetorno(resultadoServidor) {

    if (resultadoServidor.resultado) {

        toastr['success'](resultadoServidor.mensagem);

        $("#minhaModal").modal("hide");

        $("#gridDados").bootgrid("reload");

    }
    else {

        toastr['error'](resultadoServidor.mensagem);
    }

}


/* ControlarGrid.js**/


function configurarControles() {

    var traducao = {
        infos: "Exibindo {{ctx.start}} até {{ctx.end}} de {{ctx.total}} registros", // 
        loading: "Carregando, isso pode levar alguns segundos...",
        noResults: "Não há dados para exibir",
        refresh: "Atualizar",
        search: "Pesquisar"
    }

    var controlarGrid = {
        ajax: true,
        url: urlListar,
        labels: traducao,
        statusMappins: {
            0: "Finalizado",
            1: "No prazo",
            2: "Atenção próximo ao prazo do SLA",
            3: "Prazo do SLA excedido"
        },
        searchSettings: {
            characters: 2
        },
        formatters: {
            "acoes": function (column, row) {

                return "<a href='#' class='btn btn-info' data-acao='Details' data-row-id ='" + row.Id + "' > " +
                    "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-list'></span></a>"
                    +
                    "<a href='#' class='btn btn-warning' data-acao='Edit' data-row-id ='" + row.Id + "' > " +
                    "<span class= 'glyphicon glyphicon-edit'></span></a>"
                    +
                    "<a href='#' class='btn btn-danger' data-acao='Delete' data-row-id ='" + row.Id + "' > " +
                    "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></span></a>";
            },
            //"DescricaoGAreaCliente": function (column, row) {

            //    return row.GAreaCliente.Descricao;
            //}
            "DescricaoUf": function (column, row) {
                return row.Uf.Descricao;
            }
        }
    }
    var grid = $("#gridDados").bootgrid(controlarGrid);

    grid.on("loaded.rs.jquery.bootgrid", function () {

        grid.find("a.btn").each(function (index, elemento) {

            var botaoDeAcao = $(elemento);

            var acao = botaoDeAcao.data("acao");
            var idEntidade = botaoDeAcao.data("row-id");

            botaoDeAcao.on("click", function () {

                abrirModal(acao, idEntidade);

            });
        });
    });

    $("a.btn").click(function () {

        var acao = $(this).data("action");

        abrirModal(acao);
    });
}

function abrirModal(acao, parametro) {

    var url = "/{ctrl}/{acao}/{parametro}";
 
    url = url.replace("{ctrl}", controller);
    url = url.replace("{acao}", acao);

    if (parametro !== null) {

        url = url.replace("{parametro}", parametro);
    }
    else {
        url = url.replace("{parametro}", "");
    }

    $("#conteudoModal").load(url, function () {

        $("#minhaModal").modal('show');
    });

}
```

```html
<!-- index.cshtml --> 
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Area do Cliente";
}

<h2>@ViewBag.Title</h2>

<p>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-success" data-action="Create">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
        Nova
    </a>
</p>


<table id="gridDados">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th data-column-id="Area" data-order="asc">Area</th>
            @*<th data-formatter ="DescricaoGAreaCliente">Gestor da Area do Cliente</th>*@
            <th data-formatter="acoes"></th>
        </tr>

    </thead>
</table>

<div class="modal fade" id="minhaModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div id="conteudoModal"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-actions no-color">
    @Html.ActionLink("Menu Básico", "Index", "CBs")
</div>
@section scripts{
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.bootgrid.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/Projeto/ControlarGrid.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var controller = "AreaClientes";

        var urlListar = "@Url.Action("Listar")";

        $(document).ready(configurarControles);

    </script>

}


<!-- Create.cshtml  -->


@model PortalAdmCC.Models.AreaCliente

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Area do Cliente";
}

<h2>Nova</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "AreaClientes", FormMethod.Post, new { id= "formCrud" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">

        <h4>Area do Cliente</h4>

        <hr />

        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

        <div class="form-group  col-xs-8">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Area, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Area, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Area, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        @*<div class="form-group col-lg-10">
                           @Html.LabelFor(model => model.GAreaClienteId, "Gestor Area do Cliente", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
            <div class="col-lg-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("GAreaClienteId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.GAreaClienteId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>*@
    </div>

   <div class="form-group">
           <input type="button" value="Salvar" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" />
    </div>
 
}

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")

<script src="~/Scripts/Projeto/EnviarFormulario.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var btnAcao = $("input[type='button']");
    var formulario = $("#formCrud");

</script>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Edit 1:** Quando eu coloco no actionName "Create/", funciona perfeitamente

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esse `undefined`é proveniente do `JavaScript` seus helpers na View estão corretos o problema é o seu botão "Nova"

Que recebe o seguinte bind:

```
   $("a.btn").click(function () {

        var acao = $(this).data("action");

        abrirModal(acao);
    });
```

Ele não passa o argumento `parametro` para a function `abrirModal(acao, parametro)` e ela por sua vez valida apenas se o o mesmo é `null` e não `undefined`. Você pode adicionar o tratamento nela, ou simplesmente atribuir `null` em sua chamada.

```
$("a.btn").click(function () {   
   var acao = $(this).data("action");   
   abrirModal(acao, null);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

troque para Html.BeginForm("Create.cshtml", "AreaClientes"

Comment: Não funcionou  meu caro